# i am unable to save content of a form in database via Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

hello everyone i am trying to save a form in my database
**my models.py**

```
class customer(models.Model):
    customerid = models.CharField(default=str(uuid.uuid1()), max_length=500, primary_key=True)
    customername=models.CharField(max_length=1000,)
```

**my forms.py**

```
from .models import customer

class createcustomerform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=customer
        fields=['customername']
```

**my views.py**

```
def createcustomer(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        return render (request,'marketing/createcustomer.html',{'form':createcustomerform()})
    else:
        try:
            form=createcustomerform(request.POST)
            newcreatecustomer=form.save(commit=False)
            newcreatecustomer.user=request.user
            newcreatecustomer.save()
            return redirect('createcustomer')
        except ValueError:
            return render(request,'marketing/createcustomer.html',{'form':createcustomerform(),'error':'Check for Invalid Data. Try Again.'})
```

**my html is**

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div id="customernamename"> <span>Company Name</span>
      <input type="text" id="customername" placeholder="Enter Company's Full name"> </div>
</form>
```

When i am clicking save button its redirecting me again to createcustomer but not saving data in my database. kindly help what is wrong or what am i missing ?
Its saving the customer by admin area not by html page.

Comment: read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is here: `newcreatecustomer.user=request.user`

The variable `newcreatecustomer` does not have `user` field; that is why it is not working.